# UV irradiance in a cylinder

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

A uv lamp is used for the curing of the inner surface of a cylindrical tube with constant radius. The lamp moves along the cylinders centercurve. The tube is not necessarily straight.

The curing is complete when every point on the surface is exposed to a certain total UV amount (E) per area over a chosen time interval of delta seconds. It is allowed for more or less exposure outside this interval, the important thing is that during the curing process there exists a time interval where the necessary energy is transferred per area for every point on the surface.

How powerful does the lamp need to be and what does the movement along the center curve look like? This ideally needs to be expressed in variables.

Im thinking that for this we need to be able to define a circle that follows any given curve to create this ''tube''. Something where the circles center point is defined by the main curve and its direction? Is this possible?

Here is my most recent attempt:

```
#Curve for the centerline of the tube
p(t)=<f1,f2,f3>

#Equation for the circle
w(u)=[r*cos(u),r*sin(u),0]

#Describing the rotation of the circle
Rxyz(Theta)=3x3Matrix 

#Sweep:
p(t)+(dot(Rxyz,w(u))
```

Does anyone have some input? I'm stuck.
Cheers.